# `ld: cannot find -libminuit` when compiling Fortran with code the MINUIT library

Tags: linker, fortran, fortran90

I have a question to a specific F77 library. Its name is libminuit. One can download it from -> https://github.com/ramos/minuit/downloads. It supplies methods to fit a theoretical model to experimental data.

The download consists of the F77 source code (many files) and a makefile. The makefile is to produce the library.

I wrote a chi squared function in f95 code and want to use the minuit library to do the minimization.

Its the first time for me using fortran at all. I produced the library first using the F77 compiler and afterwards using the F95 compiler.

In both cases the library does not get found.

The whole process from producing the library until the compilation and linking is:

```
$ gfortran -c *.F
$ ar rcs libminuit.a *.o
$ cp libminuit.a /home/kai/TEST/f95/lib/libminuit.a
$ rm *o *a
$ nano testM.f90
$ gfortran testM.f90 -L/home/kai/TEST/f95/lib -libminuit
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libminuit
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$ cat testM.f90
```

Test source:

```
PROGRAM TESTM
call minuit(5,6,7)
END PROGRAM TESTM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When linking to a library named `libfoo.a` you need to pass the flag `-lfoo` to the compiler, not `-llibfoo`. So in your case you should use `-lminuit`, not `-libminuit`.

Comment: Thanks for the superfast reply! And yes this it is ;) it worked!

Comment: @kellekai On StackOverflow instead of saying thanks in the comments it is customary to accept the answer that solved your problem.

Comment: @kellekai Hi, I'm also in some trouble understanding what I should do to be able to use MINUIT routines. This question is some years old, and I don't know if you are still around. But if you are, could we have a discussion ? Thanks! :)